# Check if values in an array are in other array

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

I'm working on a filter for a wordpress page and I'm having trouble when trying to use multiple values.

The idea is to use a boolean to show or not show an item. Each item uses ACF to get various fields, in this case is color.

```
    if( isset($colores) ){
        foreach($colores as $color){
            if( in_array ( $color, get_field( 'color', get_the_ID() ) ) ){//Matches the filter
                $pasaColor = true;              
            }else if($color == null){//Not specified in the filter
                $pasaColor= true;               
            }else{//doesn't match the filter
                $pasaColor= false;              
            }
        }
    }
```

This works if `$colores` has only one element, like this:

```
(
    [0] => yellow        
)
```

I compare it with the values of each item:

```
(
    [0] => yellow        
    [1] => red
    [2] => blue
)
```

This result in: `$pasaColor=true`

```
(          
    [1] => red
    [2] => blue
)
```

This one results in : `$pasaColor=false`

But if the filter gives more than one element only the last one stays true.

Filter:

```
(
    [0] => yellow        
    [1] => azul
)
```

Item1:

```
    (
    [0] => yellow        
    [1] => red
    [2] => pink
)
```

This results in `$pasaColor=false`

Item2:

```
(
    [0] => blue
    [1] => red
    [2] => pink
)
```

This results in `$pasaColor=true`

In item1 the result I'm getting means that the value "yellow" cannot be found in an array that actually contains the value "yellow".

And while we are at it, is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. At each cicle on the foreach my boolean would be overwritten so in the end is is like only the last element was checked.

I added another boolean to prevent this.

```
if( isset($colores) ){
    foreach($colores as $color){
        if( in_array ( $color, get_field( 'color', get_the_ID() ) ) ){//Matches the filter
            $pasaColor = true;    
            $itempasa = true;
        }else if($color == null){//Not specified in the filter
            $pasaColor= true;     
            $itempasa = true;                  
        }else if($itempasa==false){//doesn't match the filter
            $pasaColor= false;   
            $itempasa = false;           
        }
    }
}
```

As I said before if anyone know of a better way of dealing with this please share, I would really appreciate it.